# How to save a date value in a node programatically?

Tags: nodes, hooks, datetime

I'm saving a node programmatically. Every thing works fine except the date field which gives me an error.

My date field in cck is in Date-time format as I need to capture both and the widget type is date popup.

```
$node = new StdClass();

//creating a bare node
$node->created = $value['article_creation_date'];
$node->type = 'media';
//giving it type
$node->uid = $user->uid;
$node->status = 1;

//give it a published status

$node->title = $value['article_title'];
//gives title

node_object_prepare($node);
$node->field_publish_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['value'] = date("d/m/Y H:i:s ", 1289799000);
$node->field_publish_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['timezone'] = "Asia/Kolkata";
$node->field_publish_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['timezone_db'] = "Asia/Kolkata";
$node->field_publish_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['date_type'] = "datetime";

node_save($node);
```

This is the error:

> Error is:      `PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime
>   format: 1292 Incorrect      datetime value: '15/11/2010 11:00:00 ' for
>   column 'field_date_value' at row 1: INSERT INTO
>   {field_data_field_date} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle,
>   delta, language, field_date_value) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6); Array (
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 3
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 3 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => article
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 15/11/2010 11:00:00 ) in
>   field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (line 514 of '

I'm open to suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: This is the error I am getting. "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."

Comment: @sneha.kamble that msg is not helpful. Please do this [Show all errors while developing](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/show-all-errors-while-developing) to get the real error **Switch on strict PHP error reporting**

Answer (score 3):

You are making 4 different arrays and putting part of the date config in each array.

Each time you put `[]` you are making a new array.

What you want is:

```
$node->field_publish_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][] = array(
  'value' => date("d/m/Y H:i:s ", 1289799000),
  'timezone' => "Asia/Kolkata",
  'timezone_db' => "Asia/Kolkata",
  'value' => "datetime",
);
```

Answer (score 0):

for me this solved the issue:

```
  $node->field_publish_date[LANGUAGE_NONE][]['value'] = date("d-m-Y H:i:s ", 1289799000); I just changed the date format.
```

Thanks for help.